# how to debug .prog host script in oracle

Tags: oracle, unix, putty

I have a .prog program which i have put at the bin folder. I have created the executable and concurrent program but when i run the host program i am getting the error :

```
This request finished with an error and produced the following completion message: The executable file $APPL_TOP/12.0.0/bin/XXHCM_FUSION_UCM_UPLOAD for this concurrent program cannot be executed. 

Contact your system administrator or support representative. 

Verify that the execution path to th
```

i want to debug this .prog script. how can i do that ? there is no log or output getting generated.